# How can I build a faster implementation of Queue?

Tags: performance, functional-programming, queue, ocaml

I noticed queue.ml tends to be rather slow due to its implementation based on a linked list (with a mutable field)

Is it possible to build a queue with a faster structure, like an array for instance ?

Or is there a way to achieve better performances but still in a functional way ?

**EDIT :** I want to implement a publish-subscribe solution with tens of thousands enqueue and deliver operations in less than one millisecond (for a graphic interactive application), so I need something very fast and ocaml queue implementation didn't fullfill my performance needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be interesting to know why you think the linked-list based implementation is slow.  This is the classic implementation of a queue.  Insert and delete are about as fast as I can imagine (updating one or two reference fields).  Note that I haven't looked at the code you're talking about.

You can implement a ring buffer with an array.  It might be faster for some things (like traversing all elements, say), but would have a maximum size (for the most straightforward implementation).  There are also complications in initializing the array.

Generally speaking, functional (immutable) implementations of data structures are a bit slower than the corresponding imperative (mutable) versions.  There's a very nice functional queue implementation that has great performance.  The basic trick is to keep half the queue in forward order (for fast removal) and half in reversed order (for fast insertion).  The extra pass for reversal introduces a small penalty, like I was saying.

If you're looking at memory (allocation and GC), the immutable approach will allocate the most, the classic method a medium amount, and the ring buffer will allocate very little.  But a good FP implementation (like OCaml) makes it very fast to allocate memory, and it's not too slow to reclaim it either if the objects are short-lived.

**Edit:** For what it's worth, I just ran an exceptionally crude timing test on my laptop (3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo), and I can enqueue and dequeue a million values using the standard OCaml Queue module in 70 millisec.  So then that's about .7 msec to do 10,000 (if I got that right).  It doesn't seem fast enough to do what you want if your CPU is no faster than mine.

**Edit 2:** I just hand wrote some code that assumes there's a pre-existing reference field in your values that can be used to queue them up.  This avoids doing any allocations in the queueing code, but is otherwise similar to the standard Queue module (though far less elegant).  On the same laptop as above, a million queues and dequeues takes around 48 millisec.  So it's a little faster.

**Edit 3:** Very likely you've got your answer by now, but I just ran a crude timing test using the pure queue implementation I outlined above, and I see around 18 millisec to do a million queues and dequeues.  So it's quite a bit faster.  This is plausible, as OCaml is tuned for pure computation.  Here is my code; you can check for any errors.

```
type q = {
    head: int list;
    tail: int list;
}

let q_add q i =
    { q with tail = i :: q.tail }

let q_take q =
    match q.head with
    | [] ->
        begin
        match List.rev q.tail with
        | [] -> raise Not_found
        | h :: t -> (h, { head = t; tail = [] })
        end
    | h :: t -> (h, { head = t; tail = q.tail })

let main () =
    let q = q_add { head = []; tail = [] } 0
    in let now = Unix.gettimeofday ()
    in let rec go q i =
        if i > 1_000_000 then
            q
        else
            let (_, q') = q_take (q_add q i)
            in
                go q' (i + 1)
    in let _ = go q 1
    in let duration = Unix.gettimeofday () -. now
    in
        Printf.printf "%f\n" duration

let () = main ()
```

Like I said, this is a crude test.  The queue just alternates between 1 and 2 elements in length.  I'm not sure the results would hold up in your environment.  But it's interesting.

Comment: what do you think of janestreet's [DeQueue](http://www.janestreet.com/ocaml/doc/core/Dequeue.html) solution ?

Comment: I haven't looked at their code either, but generally speaking a double-ended queue is going to be harder to implement effectively than a single-ended one because it can do more.  Have you done some timing tests?  A simple solution might work better than you think.  A millisecond is a long time.

Comment: I just tested it but the problem I needed to test q_add and q_take separately with iterative calls to simulate random enqueue and dequeue : `let test f init max =
 let t1 = Unix.gettimeofday() in
 for i = init to max do
  f i;
 done;
 let t2 = Unix.gettimeofday() in
 printf "time in milliseconds : %f" ((t2 -. t1) *. 1000.); print_newline();; let q = ref { head = []; tail = [] };; test (fun i -> q:=q_add !q i) 0 40000;; test (fun i -> q_take !q) 0 40000;;` I get something like ~2.0 millisec and ~15000.0 millisec ! Is my test just not adequate ?

Comment: It looks like you're doing 40,000 enqueues followed by 40,000 dequeues.  When I do this test I see around 2.0 msec for enqueues and 4.0 msec for dequeues.  It's slower when the data lasts longer, for sure.  It's hard to believe the 15000 msec figure, I don't see that.  To avoid cluttering SO I'll put my code here: http://psellos.com/pub/purequeue3.ml  Hope it's helpful.  Regards,

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to measure the operations to really quantify how inefficient any given implementation of the queue operations are.

That said, there are alternative data structures for different queue scenarios. Particularly if you're interested in either persistent or pure queues, or concurrent queues, then you have a few options.

*Pure data structures*

- finger tree-based queues: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree-psqueue
- pure priority queues: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pure-priority-queue
- asymptotically optimal, provably correct queues, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/meldable-heap
- queues based on binomial heaps, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pqueue

*Concurrent queues*

- STM-based queues, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bounded-tchan
- STM-based bounded queues, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rolling-queue

*Publish subscribe*

If you're looking at a publish/subscribe mechanism, perhaps consider a binding to zeromq:

- http://www.zeromq.org/

it definitely is aimed at high freq operations, and even has backs the FP community, http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:haskell

There are two different OCaml bindings to ZeroMQ: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:ocaml